# c++ how to make two vectors one with data the other points and reads only

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, reference, vector

In C++ I have 2 STL vectors `A` and `V`. `A` has data and is able to change it, `V` only points to data but reads only and can't modify it. So if these two vectors are inside a class what will be the syntax of

1. Variables definition
2. assigning `A` reference into `V`
3. get_A() and get_V() will it return a reference or a pointer?

Also If I have other normal vectors like `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` am I able to "insert" their references into `V` so that `V` can see them all one by one? For clearance `V.size()` will be equal to `A.size() + B.size() + C.size()`.

---

Sorry for confusion,I think I've asked the question in wrong way

Comment: This looks much like homework. If so, please add homework tag.

Comment: Are you attempting to have a way for a client caller to see the data but not edit it.

Comment: Are you actually asking "what is the syntax of variable definition and assignment?" or are you trying to ask "how do I implement initialization and assignment such that I get certain behavior?"

Comment: I understand that you want users to be able to insert/erase/modify vector `A`. But I am not clear what is the intention for vector `V'

Comment: @ let me be , no it's not home work it's a part of an algorithm for neural network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The vectors will be declared as

   ```
   vector<Data> A;
   vector<const Data *> V;
   ```

   (Note that V cannot be a vector of `const Data &` because references are not Assignable, and vector requires an Assignable template type.)
2. Assigning a reference from A into V would look like this:

   ```
   V[i] = &A[i];
   ```
3. I'm not sure what you mean by get_A and get_V. My best guess is that you are referring to what the results of operator[] on A and V are. `A[i]` returns a reference to a Data, that is a `Data&`. `V[i]` technically returns a reference to a const Data pointer, i.e. `const Data * &`, but effectively you would use it as a pointer, i.e. a `const Data *`.

Regarding the question about A, B, and C: if they are the all vectors of same type, and they do not change size, you could set up V to contain pointers to the elements in each one of them. But if they do change size, then appending an element to, say, A, after having set V up would mean you would have to insert the pointer to the new element of A into the correct offset of V, which is possible but seems like a hassle.

A quick example of setting up such a V would look like this:

```
vector<Data const *> V;
for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) { V.push_back(&A[i]); }
for (size_t i = 0; i < B.size(); ++i) { V.push_back(&B[i]); }
for (size_t i = 0; i < C.size(); ++i) { V.push_back(&C[i]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are describing is something like a `const` alias for the data vector. What I am saying is that you need to work with a const reference to vector `A`.

An example (completely out of the blue, but describes my suggestion and understanding of the situation quite well):

```
class someClass
{
public:
    const std::vector & V() const
    {
        return A;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> A;
};
```

From what I get from `const`ness, this "protects" `A` through showing only the `const` version when someone "accesses" the vector through `someClass::V()`.